# How to avoid creating any object within the storage that a const automatic object used to occupy?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, constants, local-variables, placement-new

The C++ (draft) standard contains what I call the "ROMability clause" that is [[basic.life]/10](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic#life-10):

> Creating a new object within the storage that a const complete object
>   with static, thread, or automatic storage duration occupies, or within
>   the storage that such a const object used to occupy before its
>   lifetime ended, results in undefined behavior.

The first part is fine: "static, thread" "storage duration". It would be unreasonable to allow the reuse of such storage.

But what about the last part:

> **automatic** storage duration occupies, or within
>   the storage that **such a const object used to occupy** before its
>   lifetime ended

Does that mean that **the user needs to be avoid creating any object in any memory location that might have been used by the stack (to store automatic objects)**?

That would prevent the use of placement new on any subobject of an automatic object, or to use a library tool that does such thing.

That makes zero sense, yet it seems to me that it's literally what's specified here.

Comment: The "const" is significant.

Comment: @molbdnilo Significant how?

Comment: Because the compiler wants to be able to assume that a const object doesn't change.

Comment: @molbdnilo (a) I don't see how that's relevant. Why wouldn't the user be allowed to reuse the storage of a const object then? (b) Are you saying that this is illegal: `void f() { int i = 1; int *p = new(&i) int(2); *p = 3; }`

Comment: @molbdnilo (a) Suppose it was. Then what?

Comment: The `i` is not const, so this section does not apply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204169/discussion-between-curiousguy-and-molbdnilo).

Comment: "But what about the last part" - you snipped half of two clauses to make something unintended. The whole quote is only about `const` objects .  It would improve the question to show some code that you think is apparently ruled out

Comment: @M.M Any code that creates an object is ruled out.

Comment: @curiousguy it's hard to understand how you think a paragraph about re-using storage of a `const` object means that creation of any object is ruled out

Comment: @M.M How do you know that the object wasn't created within the storage etc.?

Comment: "_you snipped half of two clauses to make something unintended_" I only skipped the part that isn't the subject of the question. I'm neither interested (at the moment) in what happens when you reuse the storage of static objects nor thread storage location. The issue here is exclusively what could happen when you reuse the storage of automatic objects: "the storage that such a const object used to occupy before its lifetime ended". **Where are these "dead" objects in memory?**

Comment: "Where are these "dead" objects in memory?" , a dead object isn't anywhere per se . You can end the lifetime of a const object in automatic storage (e.g. via destructor call, within constraint of the rules) and then you have some storage in which , you can't create new objects.   If you do this and then randomly at some other point of the program try to create a new object in the storage then it's UB, there's no way the compiler could track this and it is the coder's mistake for being sloppy. In fact it will be UB anyway when the scope ends so it was a bad idea in the first place

Comment: I guess I missed to whole concept of "storage" and its relation with variables.

Answer (score 8):

> the user needs to be avoid creating any object in any memory location that might have been used by the stack (to store automatic objects)

The standard doesn't know about "the stack" nor does it care - it's an implementation detail.

> Block-scope variables not explicitly declared static, thread_­local, or extern have automatic storage duration.
>
> **The storage for these entities lasts until the block in which they are created exits**
>
> from [[basic.stc.auto]](https://eel.is/c++draft/basic.stc.auto)

Thus even if two entities end up being - without overlapping storage - at the same address "on the stack" they still don't have the same storage.

```
union Lazy {
  Thing thing;
};

// later in a function
{
  Thing const first = /* init */
}
{
  Lazy l;
  new (&l.thing) Thing();
}
```

`first` and `l.thing` possibly will be on the same address ... but when `l.thing` is created the storage of `first` is already "gone".

**"Bottom line": same address does not imply same storage.**

Comment: OK so the compiler **creates** the storage for each variable?

Comment: "Yes" .. the storage is handled automatically ... which in practice means the compiler generating instructions to manage the stack. But "the storage" is a concept specified by the standard ... what the compiler produces is an implementation of that concept.

Comment: I understand that stack storage is provided automatically by the generated code. I don't where in the std it's specified that one storage is created for each local variable, or any clear explanation of when storage is created by the compiler.

Answer (score 2):

`Storage` is an abstract designation of resource used to store the object at given time. It might be a CPU register, volatile\nonvolatile memory, cache and combination of those.

This clause means only that compiler is allowed to assume that such object is unchanged. The duration   only is different. If `static` one or a global `const` (which is automatically `static`) can be assumed to never change in whole program, local ones  are assumed to never change during evaluation of all expressions involving it in scope.

```
// static duration
const int v1 = 3; // is always 3, variable may or may not exist, 
                  // depending on type and whether address was requested.
                  // for linkage purposes considered static

void foo(int a)
{
  // static duration
  static const int v2 = 3; // initialized with 3  on first call of foo()

  // automatic storage duration
  const int v3 = a + v;    // initialized every time, 
                           //  is just a local variable that cannot be changed
                           //  storage stops to exist after foo() returned
}
```

This means that storage occupied by `v3` never persist outside of `foo()`'s execution and its address - pointer or reference - shouldn't be returned or otherwise used outside of scope (e.g. by capturing). Outside of `foo()` any other object may be placed into same "storage", but it's not same storage from abstract point of view used by standard. This doesn't apply to resources allocated by automatic const object, e.g. they might be moved to be owned by some other object.

Comment: So each and every variable gets its own storage, and the storage disappears after? So the compiler never reuses storage. I get it.

Comment: @curiousguy in abstract, yes. In reality, storage is a "calling card" in compiler's memory during creation of code. For static const objects that may be an address or real value, in latter case compiler would save it into CPu instruction. Too big objects will be hard-coded into binary image and their address will be used.Compiler even may glue some values together, e.g. to write a 64-bit value instead of 4 16-bit ones. For automatic ones it may be CPU instruction or register, but value likely would come from CPU instruction anyway.